# radio button list with text option cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, radio-button

I am new to CakePHP. I need to make a form with radio buttons and the last one is "other" where the user can type in an answer in a text box.

Is there any way FormHelper can do this that's built in?

One way I was going to do was create a radio list and a text field. When "other" is selected Javascript will show the text field. For this I don't understand how to use any other variables besides the fields in the database. How does one create a variable from a model that can be accessed from a view and the value returned for processing?

For the model I have:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Display field
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $displayField = 'title';
    var $sourceOther = ' ';
    var $passwordRepeat = ' ';


    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = sha1(
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
//        $this->data[$this->alias]['created']= CakeTime::gmt();
//        $this->data[$this->alias]['updated']= CakeTime::gmt();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['username']= $this->data[$this->alias]['email'];

        return true;
```

In the view I have

```
echo $this->Form->input('mobilePhone',array(
    'label'=>'Mobile or fixed phone with no spaces'));
echo $this->Form->input('alternatePhone');
echo $this->Form->input('leadSource', array(
    'options'=>array('Google'=>'Google','OnlineAd'=>'Online Ad',
            'Printed Media'=>'Printed Media','LetterDrop'=>'Letter Drop',
            'Other'=>'Other (specify text)'),
    'empty'=>'(choose one)')); 
echo $this->Form->input($this->sourceOther);
```

...but it doesn't like sourceOther, the variable in the model. How do I get data from the view (the text box) into the user model so beforeSave can do something with it?

Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Where your code ??? you should be give a snapshot of your code.

Comment: Added it there now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out after reading "Cake PHP Application Development". It works for Cake 2.x and 1.2 (as used in the book).

In your view put:

```
echo $this->Form->input('sourceOther');
```

Then in the model you can access your variable with:

```
$this->data['User']['sourceOther'];
```

For example, use it to save "other" text field in beforesave:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = sha1(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    $this->data[$this->alias]['username'] = $this->data[$this->alias]['email'];

    $this->data[$this->alias]['activation'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

    if ($this->data[$this->alias]['leadSource'] == 'Other') {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['leadSource'] =
                $this->data['User']['sourceOther'];
    }
    return true;
}
```